# How we can do a class diagram for NodeJS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, uml, class-diagram

I am planning to implement an application with Node API for my final year project. We need to draw the class diagram. As I know there is no class concept in Node JS like Java / C#. So what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can make class diagrams only if you have classes. When you target programming languages like Cxx/Java they already have language constructs for classes. So pretty easy in that case.

Now, if you use languages that don't support class constructs directly you need to have conceptual classes. A class is a something that binds attributes and operations to some logical unit. That can be done in procedural (and even esotheric) languages. In that case you use naming conventions. E.g. you use prefixes denoting class members (attributes and operations). By the prefix you can identify the class. Of course the instantiation of classes is more difficult in that way but it is doable.

As a side note: 40 years ago I had a lecture at university with Prof. Floyd. She was teaching object oriented programming. Using COBOL! Why? Because it's one of the most difficult ways to learn it and you definitely learn if for your life.